# custom login query for custom login form?

Tags: wp-login-form

I have a custom multi-step form which collects user data and other detailed information, in the last step it has 2 options for user,
1) asks user to enter login details and submit to save record
2) to sign up/register and on submit store data and auto create account.

**For step 2**, I have used `wp_insert_user()` to create user and `$wpdb->insert` to save other detailed information of that user in record.

**Note**: I'm doing my all code on the same page as I'm not good in using functions,
`if ( $_POST['register_account'] ) { //wp_insert_user() //$wpdb->insert; }`

**For Step 1**, I have tried to use `wp_signon()` but it gives me `Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by`.

All I need is a simple custom login query to logged in and after login shows the user selected information from the previous steps of this form and on Confirmation, save this record to this login usermeta.
`if ( $_POST['login_account'] ) { //logged in and show data; }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest to read how the filters and hooks work inside WordPress [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API), that's the easiest way (and the recommended one) to add/alter the site functionality.

The `wp_insert_user()` function returns the new created user ID so I wouldn't use a custom query for inserting user records since you can use `add_user_meta()`: [see the docs here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_user_meta)

You have to call `wp_signon()` before outputting any HTML, see the notes from the function docs:  https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_signon

- This function sends headers to the page. It must be run before any content is returned
- This function sets an authentication cookie. Users will not be logged in if it is not sent.

Comment: Many thanks @Pabamato. Can you please guide me how `custom_login()` [in reference link example] from `wp_signon()` works? If a user clicks on submit button from my custom mutistep form, how `wp_signon()` function will work and perform login?

Comment: HI @max can't provide feedback without seeing your code but the idea is that you perform server validation for the form step 1 and if valid then you can call the `wp_signon()` function and then redirect to page 2 of the form.

Comment: Thanks @Pabamato it works like a magic, but I'm still wondering how it knows to run that function without having any submit name, i.e `<input type="submit" name="login_account">`

Comment: I have another situation. You can find the code below. Thanks

Comment: `<form><input name="username" type="text" /><input name="password" type="password" /><input type="submit" name="login_account">`. I have placed `wp_signon()` in functions file and its working and make user logged in. But I also want to hide form after login and show user info here. `if ( $_POST['login_account'] ) { //show userinfo } else { //hideform }` , but `$_POST['login_account']' check is not working.

Comment: Hi @max I would recommend to use the WordPress built in conditional tags: https://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags
For your case ´is_user_logged_in()´ will work

Comment: sorry to bother you again and again. I have a **serious** issue. I'm copying `wp_signon()` function from this link https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_signon. But after submitting form, it can't login nor show admin top menubar, but when I **refresh** page again, now user become login and admin top bar appears.

Comment: Hi @max to me it looks  like you are sending the authentication cookies after outputting the page content, but can't tell without seeing your code.
Please consider opening a new question or edit the current one, also please rate it if you consider the answers provided were helpful. Many thanks. Pablo

Comment: so nice of you @Pabamato, I really appreciate your help. Many thanks. I will update my question with my code very soon.